# CDVUserAgentUtil.h' file not found in cordova iOS 6.1.0

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I'm new to ionic. My app works fine and builds properly on android but on iOS I have to fetch the "CDVUserAgentUtil.h' file not found" issue.

- Cordova : 6.1.0
- Ionic : 6.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing the `webview` problems, depending which plugin are you using in your App you will have this problems. The Apple only accepts Apps that are using the updated `Webkview`. Check if you are using some `Cordova File System` plugin and update it. You can also install the [Ionic Webview](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ionic-webview) plugin in your App to solve this.

Another good solution could be using `Capacitor` for building your Apps.